# Cannot get input value set by Javascript and then read by Blazor button click

Tags: javascript, .net, blazor

Inside a .NET 5 blazor application I use a javascript library for barcode reading. When I press a button on blazor page I call javascript function. Javascript function reads the barcode and sets value of an input field.

There is an input field bound to string value:

```
<input id="result" @bind="@Received"/>

@code { private string Received { get; set; } }
```

A button click calls javascript function:

```
public async Task Start()
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("startBarcodeReader");
}
```

Javascript function sets value of input field:

```
document.getElementById('result').value = "Barcode Value";
```

Everything works as I expected and I see barcode value on my screen. I would like to use `Received` when I click another button. However bound value is null. It is not set.

```
public async Task Add()
{
    // Received is null
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

If I manually type something into input field then value of Received variable is set. It seems that binding is not set bound variable unless focus is lost.

How can I get the value I see in input field? I tried to use oninout event of inout field and did not work.

Comment: you need to call a .Net method back to Blazor to set Received

Comment: @aguafrommars I checked https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-dotnet-from-javascript/ and this seemed a little bit unnecessary extra effort to get such value. There must be a simpler way.

Comment: As far I know there isn't. Read the official doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: One way could be to change the behavior of 'startBarcodeReader' to actually return the barcode, and change the JSInterop function to one that accepts a return value. Another option might be to try and read the barcode from some js variable when you actually want it. I have personally added a global helper script that I can call using JSinterop from wherever to access js properties.

Comment: Yeah I am lost. I outsourced the file. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule, your JS code should not interfere in any way with the rendering and bounding features of Blazor. Thus, you cannot assign a value to an input field in JavaScript and expect this value to pass to the bounding variable `Received`. This can never occur. How can Blazor know that the value of the input field has changed ! Is there any event listener attached to the input field that is to notify Blazor that a value has been entered ? None.

Solution: Pass the value to a Blazor method in which you can update the variable `Received`... After that the component will re-render, and the input field will show the same value inside it, but this time it is done by the rendering and bounding features of Blazor.

Note: You can employ `DotNetObjectReference` to call your JavaScript, passing it a reference to a C# object that defines a method to receive the value of the barcode when called from JavaScript.

Comment: @Michel Jansson return value suggestion did not worked because barcode reader runs continuously, value comes in undefined time when a barcode is deteced and read. Thank you very much for the information. Solves the problem. Besides global helper function idea from Michel Jansson to access js properties also works.